# Using Castle Windsor to inject dependencies when the classes inherit from the same base class

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

I have two classes that inherit from the same base class.

```
public class UserDetailValidator : BaseValidator<UserDetail>{
    public UserDetailValidator(IRepository<Person, Guid> userRepository, AddressValidator addressValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).Length(1, 10);
    }
}

public class AddressValidator : BaseValidator<Address>
```

When I try and get the UserDetailValidator from WindsorServiceLocator I get the error

Missing dependency.
Component UserDetailValidator has a dependency on AddressValidator, which could not be resolved.
Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a service, or provided as inline argument.  I'm using the following in my ValidationInstaller.

```
container.Register(
AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Validation")
        .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
    .BasedOn(typeof(IValidator<>))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestyleTransient()
```

The IRepository component is being injected with no problems.  It's only the AddressValidator that does not come in.  What am I not doing properly?  I'm using Castle Windsor 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I changed the type of the Argument being passed 
to UserDetailValidator from AddressValidator to IValidator. 
I still have to use AllInterfaces (at least in my testing so far) but 
it now works.